# How to configure polkadot + parachain locally to validate parachain block each 6 sec?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, substrate-parachain-template, relay-chain, substrate-block-time

I want to spin up parachain LOCALLY faster. each 6 sec.
How to configure polkadot with parachain?

I have seen [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4454/block-times-in-parachain-are-twice-as-long-as-configured) and [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4558/why-my-solo-chain-block-time-is-12-seconds-when-set-to-6)
and [this post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/what-is-the-possible-minimum-block-time)

So my zombienet contains
polkadot(obviusly)
and two parachains. each of them with one collator node.

I changed relaychain

```
pub const MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK: u64 = 3000;
```

and now relay chain produce the block each 3 sec. it is good.

[image]

I changed for parachain runtime. the value. from 12000 to 6000

```
pub const MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK: u64 = 6000;
```

BUT parachain still produce the block each 12 sec instead of 6
even when relay chain produce block each 3 sec.

I understand that i need to reconfigure relay chain to sign and send transaction to parachain more often. `set_validate_data` extrinisc in parachain system

[image]

Comment: This may help: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4558/why-my-solo-chain-block-time-is-12-seconds-when-set-to-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

polkadot/service/chain_spec.rs
**will override**

```
MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK
```

So you do not need change `MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK` directly.
You need to change

session_length_in_blocks

```
#[cfg(feature = "rococo-native")]
pub fn rococo_development_config() -> Result<RococoChainSpec, String> {
    let wasm_binary = rococo::WASM_BINARY.ok_or("Rococo development wasm not available")?;

        Ok(RococoChainSpec::from_genesis(
            "Development",
            "rococo_dev",
            ChainType::Development,
            move || RococoGenesisExt {
                runtime_genesis_config: rococo_development_config_genesis(wasm_binary),
                // Use 1 minute session length.
                session_length_in_blocks: Some(10),
            },
            vec![],
            None,
            Some(DEFAULT_PROTOCOL_ID),
            None,
            None,
            Default::default(),
        ))
    }
```

Because the value of `MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK`
will be overided byt this code

```
#[cfg(feature = "rococo-native")]
impl sp_runtime::BuildStorage for RococoGenesisExt {
    fn assimilate_storage(&self, storage: &mut sp_core::storage::Storage) -> Result<(), String> {
        sp_state_machine::BasicExternalities::execute_with_storage(storage, || {
            if let Some(length) = self.session_length_in_blocks.as_ref() {
                rococo_runtime_constants::time::EpochDurationInBlocks::set(&length);
            }
        });
        self.runtime_genesis_config.assimilate_storage(storage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the relay chain and parachain locally follow https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/prepare-a-local-relay-chain/.

The above tutorial will help you set up a relay chain locally and also will tell you how to connect a local parachain to it, after setting up the chain you can configure it according to your needs.

Comment: thanks. i aware about how to run locally. i am interested how to configure relaychain + parachain to produce block faster for parachain. at least every 6 sec instead of 12 sec.

Comment: it should have worked by changing the `MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK`, time also doesn't changed on parachain's explorer as well?

Comment: Once i changed MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK for parachain runtime it does not work.
Still 12 sec per block instead of 6. even when relay chain produces the block each 3 sec.